# CouchDB with V8 instead SpiderMonkey

Tags: couchdb, v8

How can I run CouchDB with V8 JavaScript engine instead native JS based SpiderMonkey?
I found this project https://github.com/dachev/couchv8, but it's outdated.

Comment: You'd have to recompile the project yourself, and I doubt it's as easy as just dropping it in place. Why do you need V8 over SpiderMonkey?

Comment: Because it's so much faster?

Comment: I think it may be faster, but I can't set up this https://github.com/iriscouch/couchjs